# Define own XMLEventReader to implement the Closeable interface

Tags: java, interface, autocloseable

I'd like to use try-with-resources with the `XMLEventReader`.

As I found out, `XMLEventReader` is just an interface and the object I get from `XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(stream)` is of the `com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl` class.

Normally I would extend that class to implement `Closeable`. But I'm not able to access it (I can't open it in my IDE).
I found its code online. But I'm not willing to copy it to a new class, just to make it closeable.

So why can't I access that class and what's the best solution to make a `Closeable` `XMLEventReader`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
public class CloseableXmlEventReader implements XMLEventReader, AutoCloseable{

    private final XMLEventReader internal;

    public CloseableXmlEventReader(XMLEventReader internal) {
        this.internal = internal;
    }

    @Override
    public XMLEvent nextEvent() throws XMLStreamException {
        return internal.nextEvent();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return internal.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public XMLEvent peek() throws XMLStreamException {
        return internal.peek();
    }

    @Override
    public String getElementText() throws XMLStreamException {
        return internal.getElementText();
    }

    @Override
    public XMLEvent nextTag() throws XMLStreamException {
        return internal.nextTag();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return internal.getProperty(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws XMLStreamException {
        internal.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Object next() {
        return internal.next();
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
try(CloseableXmlEventReader reader = 
        new CloseableXmlEventReader(XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream("test.xml")))) {

} catch (XMLStreamException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(CloseableXmlEventReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Okay, that would work. But it wouldn't be the solution which I'd prefer. Because if something changes in the `XMLEventReader` interface/`XMLEventReaderImpl` class, I'd have to adapt these changes to my `CloseableXmlEventReader` class (when a method is added/removed for instance).

Comment: I think a change to XMLEventReader's interface is extremely unlikely.  I have never implemented an interface from the standard libraries and later had them add/remove a function breaking my implementation.  You really can't use any class or implement any interface and not have your code break if functions you use are removed or the interface adds more required functions. Even if it happened the fix would be really easy just another one-line function.